# Can I make two node Hadoop 2 Cluster on two different VirtualBoxes on two different lap-tops on the same network?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, cluster, hadoop

So I have two lap-tops with VirtualBox both running Ubuntu 18.4 and I am trying to set up Hadoop 2 Cluster. One VB to be the master and one VB to be the slave is it possible and how? Because all the tutorials I found were for master and slave on same the laptop with cloned VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  it is possible to create a hadoop cluster with 2 different virtual boxes, as long as they are on the same network.

The following cloudera blog may help you with the setup
https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/01/how-to-create-a-simple-hadoop-cluster-with-virtualbox/

Comment: I saw this tutorial but this is again on one one lap-top, in my case when I run start-all.sh it doen’t start the datanode and the node manager on the slave.

Comment: Probably the VBs are not connected to LAN or the firewall is blocking it.